# Is there anyway i could use turtle bot with gazebo?

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been looking forward using turtlebot on gazebo simulator. Currently i have ROS lunar with me.

---

I have already tried things written in indigo but its doesn't work with lunar? has any of you work with lunar and turtlebot at same time? for example i tried using keyboard for movements its says "command is unrecognized" something like that. any one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280503/is-there-anyway-i-could-use-turtle-bot-with-gazebo?/) by [HassanM](https://answers.ros.org/users/33385/hassanm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-23**:
Please don't use an *answer* to provide more information. This isn't a forum. Please update your question with what you've tried and the results and the tutorials that you've gone through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the [tutorials for `turtlebot_gazebo`](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_gazebo/Tutorials). You'll have to click on the "Indigo" button but everything should be pretty much the same for Indigo and Lunar.

Please note that I found this by typing:

```
turtlebot gazebo tutorial
```

into Google as a search term.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0